# Rcpp function to select (and to return) a sub-dataframe

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to write a C++ function that gets an R dataFrame as input, then modifies the dataFrame (in our case taking a subset) and returns the new data frame (in this question, returning a sub-dataframe) ?
My code below may make my question more clear:

**code**:

```
# Suppose I have the data frame below created in R:
myDF = data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2), each = 5), alph = letters[1:10], mess = rnorm(10))

# Suppose I want to write a C++ function that gets id as inout and returns 
# a sub-dataframe corresponding to that id (**If it's possible to return 
# DataFrame in C++**)

# Auxiliary function --> helps get a sub vector:
arma::vec myVecSubset(arma::vec vecMain, arma::vec IDVec, int ID){
  arma::uvec AuxVec = find(IDVec == ID);
  arma::vec rslt = arma::vec(AuxVec.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < AuxVec.size(); i++){
    rslt[i] = vecMain[AuxVec[i]];
  }
  return rslt;
}

# Here is my C++ function:
Rcpp::DataFrame myVecSubset(Rcpp::DataFrame myDF, int ID){
  arma::vec id = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(myDF["id"]);
  arma::vec alph = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(myDF["alpha"]);
  arma::vec mess = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(myDF["mess"]);

  // here I take a sub-vector:
  arma::vec id_sub = myVecSubset(id, id, int ID);
  arma::vec alph_sub = myVecSubset(alph, id, int ID);
  arma::vec mess_sub = myVecSubset(mess, id, int ID);

  // here is the CHALLENGE: How to combine these vectors into a new data frame???
  ???
}
```

In summary, there are actually two main question:
1) Is there any better way to take the sub-dataframe above in C++? (wish I could simple say myDF[myDF$id == ID,]!!!)

2) Is there anyway that I can combine id_sub, alpha_sub, and mess_sub into an R data frame and return it?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo` for that, you can just use R's `subset` or perhaps `dplyr::filter`. This is likely to be more efficient than your code that has to deep copy data from the data frame into armadillo vectors, create new armadillo vectors, and then copy these back into R vectors so that you can build the data frame. This produces lots of waste. Another source of waste is that you `find` three times the same exact thing

Anyway, to answer your question, just use `DataFrame::create`.

```
DataFrame::create( _["id"] = id_sub, _["alpha"] = alph_dub, _["mess"] = mess_sub ) ;
```

Also, note that in your code, `alpha` will be a factor, so `arma::vec alph = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(myDF["alpha"]);` is not likely to do what you want.

Answer (score 10):

To add on to Romain's answer, you can try calling the `[` operator through Rcpp. If we understand how `df[x, ]` is evaluated (ie, it's really a call to `"[.data.frame"(df, x, R_MissingArg)` this is easy to do:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

Function subset("[.data.frame");

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame subset_test(DataFrame x, IntegerVector y) {
  return subset(x, y, R_MissingArg);
}

/*** R
df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3])
subset_test(df, c(1L, 2L))
*/
```

gives me

```
> df <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3])
> subset_test(df, c(1L, 2L))
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
```

Callbacks to R can generally be slower in Rcpp, but depending on how much of a bottleneck this is it could still be fast enough for you.

Be careful though, as this function will use 1-based subsetting rather than 0-based subsetting for integer vectors.

Comment: Thanks @KevinUshey, very helpful. Yes, the indexing part makes things a bit complicated when we move back and forth between R and C++. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete test file. It does not need your extractor function and just re-assembles the subsets -- but for that it needs the very newest Rcpp as currently on GitHub where Kevin happens to have added some work on subset indexing which is just what we need here:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

/*** R
##  Suppose I have the data frame below created in R:
##  NB: stringsAsFactors set to FALSE
##  NB: setting seed as well
set.seed(42)
myDF <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2), each = 5), 
                   alph = letters[1:10], 
                   mess = rnorm(10), 
                   stringsAsFactor=FALSE)
*/

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::DataFrame extract(Rcpp::DataFrame D, Rcpp::IntegerVector idx) {

  Rcpp::IntegerVector     id = D["id"];
  Rcpp::CharacterVector alph = D["alph"];
  Rcpp::NumericVector   mess = D["mess"];

  return Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("id")    = id[idx],
                                 Rcpp::Named("alpha") = alph[idx],
                                 Rcpp::Named("mess")  = mess[idx]);
}

/*** R
extract(myDF, c(2,4,6,8))
*/
```

With that file, we get the expected result:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/sepher.cpp")

R> ##  Suppose I have the data frame below created in R:
R> ##  NB: stringsAsFactors set to FALSE
R> ##  NB: setting seed as well
R> set.seed(42)

R> myDF <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2), each = 5), 
+                    alph = letters[1:10], 
+                    mess = rnorm(10), 
+               .... [TRUNCATED] 

R> extract(myDF, c(2,4,6,8))
  id alpha     mess
1  1     c 0.363128
2  1     e 0.404268
3  2     g 1.511522
4  2     i 2.018424
R>
R> packageDescription("Rcpp")$Version   ## unreleased version
[1] "0.11.1.1"
R>
```

I just needed something similar a few weeks ago (but not involving character vectors) and used Armadillo with its `elem()` functions using an `unsigned int` vector as index.

Comment: In fact, the subsetting operations made their way into the most recent CRAN release :)

Comment: I actually checked that -- the file I posted here will not build with 0.11.1 as on CRAN.

Comment: Ahh, you're right, there were some tweaks that didn't make it into the recent release. My bad -- for now, one should use the latest GitHub version to avoid these issues.

Comment: No worries. We'll get to 0.11.2, and this will make a nice enhancement.